# SQLite Database Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, sqlite

I am new to iOS development.
I am working on a application that reads data from SQLite Database and stores in Shared Instance's(Single Tone Class) NSMutable Array. 
Later on from NSMutableArray I am assigning values to Custom Table Cell.
But while running application, application is terminating with message :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[Name isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6824fe0'
```

Following is part of code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomTableViewCell";

CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.menuNameLabel.text=[_hotelMenu._menuList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.menuImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"veg.png"];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? It might be crashed from other method rather than `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thanks for including a snippet of code. How about showing the line of code that calls "isEqualToString:"?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're invoking `isEqualToString` with a Name object.  (Never mind that the pointer type is "NSString", the object is a Name object -- the Objective-C runtime doesn't care a whit about pointer types.)

So you need to figure out why.  It could be a simple goof, or it could be a messy storage issue.  But for starters you need to actually look at the error message and the stack tracekback that should be adjacent to it and figure where the error's occurring, and hence which pointer variable is involved.